# new process created using fork but printing same address for variables

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

I have the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    printf("before: %d %p\n",a,&a);
    int t=fork();
    if(t==0)
    {
        a=a+5;
        printf("child: %d %p\n",a,&a);
    }
    else
    {
        a=a+10;
        printf("parent: %d %p\n",a,&a);
    }
    //printf("both: %d %p\n",a,&a);
    return 0;
}
```

Why all the addresses are printed same? I thought a new copy of the variables are created when fork is called. Does it have anything to do with virtual address and physical address? If so how the same virtual address gets mapped to different physical addresses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The addresses are the same because each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) (parent & child) has its *own* [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Linux computers have [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (provided by the kernel & the processor).

The [`fork` system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) is "magically" copying the virtual address space of the parent process into the virtual address space of the child process (except for the result of `fork`). This copying uses lazy [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) techniques so is quite efficient. The kernel is managing the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) (used for virtual memory and to implement each virtual address space)

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (it has several chapters related to that) & carefully [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).

BTW, take the habit of calling `fflush(NULL);` *before* `fork`. See [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush3.html).

Comment: Ok! thank you. I didn't actually get how two processes with same virtual address will be mapped to different physical addresses. But I think I should read more first and then ask.

Comment: The kernel is managing the MMU so is able to configure it likewise.

Answer (score 4):

Because Unix systems uses *virtual* addresses, and `fork` creates an exact copy of the parent process. This exact copy of course includes the (initial) memory map.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what `fork` does.  Per [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):

> The `fork()` function shall create a new process. **The new process
>   (child process) shall be an exact copy of the calling process** (parent
>   process) except as detailed below:
>
> - The child process shall have a unique process ID.
> - The child process ID also shall not match any active process group    ID.
> - The child process shall have a different parent process ID, which    shall be the process ID of the calling process.
> - The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's file    descriptors. Each of the child's file descriptors shall refer to the
>     same open file description with the corresponding file descriptor of
>     the parent.
> - The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's open    directory streams. Each open directory stream in the child process
>     may share directory stream positioning with the corresponding
>     directory stream of the parent.
> - The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's message    catalog descriptors.
> - The child process values of tms_utime, tms_stime, tms_cutime, and    tms_cstime shall be set to 0.
> - The time left until an alarm clock signal shall be reset to zero, and    the alarm, if any, shall be canceled; see alarm.
> - [XSI] [Option Start] All semadj values shall be cleared. [Option End]
> - File locks set by the parent process shall not be inherited by the    child process.
> - The set of signals pending for the child process shall be initialized    to the empty set.
> - [XSI] [Option Start] Interval timers shall be reset in the child    process. [Option End]
> - Any semaphores that are open in the parent process shall also be open    in the child process.
> - [ML] [Option Start] The child process shall not inherit any address    space memory locks established by the parent process via calls to
>     mlockall() or mlock(). [Option End]
> - Memory mappings created in the parent shall be retained in the child    process. MAP_PRIVATE mappings inherited from the parent shall
>     also be    MAP_PRIVATE mappings in the child, and any modifications to
>     the data    in these mappings made by the parent prior to calling
>     fork() shall be    visible to the child. Any modifications to the data
>     in MAP_PRIVATE    mappings made by the parent after fork() returns
>     shall be visible    only to the parent. Modifications to the data in
>     MAP_PRIVATE mappings    made by the child shall be visible only to the
>     child.
>
>   ....